# Multiple element selection using AND/OR

Tags: jquery

I'm unsure of the syntax for multiple selection. What I mean by that is taking your standard click element function:

```
$("#target").click(function () {});
```

which means `if #target is clicked then do function`

and making it mean `if #target or #target2 or #target3 is clicked then do function`

or `if #target1 and #target2 are hovered over, then do function`

I know I can just do a click function for each one but that seems like a waste of space, so how would I code that more concisely?

Thanks.

Comment: "if #target1 and #target2 are hovered over" - do you mean intersection? If not, just detect if the top one (with higher z-index) is hovered over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put them all in one selector, separated by a comma:

```
$("#target1, #target2, #target3").click(function () {});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("#target1, #target2, #target3").on('click',
       function () {
          //some code here
        }
);
```

Multiple selectors are seperated by a `,`.

**OR**

```
$('[id ^= "target"]').on('click',
        function () {
              //some code here
       }
);
```

`^=` means that all ids start with `target`.

Answer (score 1):

just use `,` between all the selectors you need

```
$("#target, #target2, #target3").click(function () {});
```